# Error while using DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: errors

I encounter an error while using my `\norm` command in conjunction with my `\LpOmega` command as an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand*{\norm}[2][{}]{\Norm*{#2}_{#1}}

\newcommand*{\Lp}[2]{L^{#2}(#1)}
\newcommand*{\LpOmega}[2][{}]{L^{#2}(\Omega_{#1})}

\begin{document}
    \[\norm[\LpOmega[1]{2}]{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i}\]
    \[\norm[{\LpOmega[1]{2}}]{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i}\]
    \[\norm[\Lp{\Omega_1}{2}]{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i}\]
\end{document}
```

The first line of code in the document causes the error `Argument of \\LpOmega has an extra }.`, while the second and third line produce the desired outcome. So it has to do with the optional argument `[1]` of `\LpOmega`. Can someone explain this error to me and show me a way to fix it without having to put an extra pair of parentheses each time? I would prefer to continue using the `\LpOmega[]{}` construction as it is very convenient for me.

Additional question: Is there a difference in defining the optional parameters of `\LpOmega` and `\norm` via `[{}]` or `[]` or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brackets are not paired, so in `\norm[\LpOmega[1]{2}]` the first closing brace finishes the optional argument and LaTeX gets `\LpOmega[1` as  optional argument which goes wrong.

You can define your command with \NewDocumentCommand. It will correctly pair the brackets. I changed the class as the minimal.cls is not suited for real examples, it is too minimal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\norm}{O{}m}{\Norm*{#2}_{#1}}

\newcommand*{\Lp}[2]{L^{#2}(#1)}
\newcommand*{\LpOmega}[2][]{L^{#2}(\Omega_{#1})}

\begin{document}
    \[\norm[\LpOmega[1]{2}]{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i}\]
    \[\norm[{\LpOmega[1]{2}}]{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i}\]
    \[\norm[\Lp{\Omega_1}{2}]{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had to add \usepacke{xparse} to your example to make it work on my machine but this looks like a nice solution to me, thank you!

Comment: @bongobums then you're using an older latex installation, most of xparse gas been in the kernel since late 2020

Comment: @daleif Good to know. It's time to update my LaTeX installation!